# Need to make my python web application self-monitoring (keep-alive) like a daemon

Tags: python, daemon

I wrote my python web application with BaseHTTPServer. It is intended to run in localhost and serve localhost requests. It is intended to be hosted in a major VPS.

So I need some reliable way to **keep it alive**. Apache (and what's being served under it) can easily re-spawn when it's stopped. Similarly, I can make CRON do a "tomcat start" periodically, so that it starts up *if it went down*.

How do I make my python app also alive? I prefer something that responds to commands from CRON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a process monitor, like the previously mentioned [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), but there's a lot of alternatives to choose from, like [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/), [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) Et.c.

I've only used supervisord myself, and it has got an XMLRPC-interface which you could use from your other applications, i.e. something that's run by CRON.

Answer (score 4):

First approach would be using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). Another option is to use [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) and create a system-wide init-script that is started when system boots.

Also, for a quick hack - you can run the app inside the detachable shell like [screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be something along the lines of the self monitoring scripts (using `subprocess`) outlined here (this might not be the most comprehensive reference, but should get you on your way):
http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=377